# How to select more than one column data in MS SQL stored procedure select query in mule

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to retrieve 2 column data using a simple select query in stored procedure. I'm getting output when running in sql server management studio. But executing same query in mulesoft Anypoint studio, I'm getting error

> Procedure or function sample1 has too many arguments specified.

Here is the stored procedure created:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sample1] @hidden INT
AS
SELECT geo_name,id_definition
FROM geo
WHERE flag_hidden = @hidden
GO
```

and here is mule flow implementation screenshots:

[image: Please check image for mule implementation of stored procedure]

Here is the error screenshot:

[image: Error of Mule flow]

Comment: Your defining output parameters `geo_name` and `id_definition`. They're not output parameters, they're not parameters, they're the result set.

Comment: thank you.. your input helped me.. We have to use select * from table name and in mule for calling procedure, we need to pass only input parameters i.e. ( {call sample1(:UP_RUN_ID)} ), not output parameters (firstname, lastname)..

Comment: But when have to retreive only first_name, last_name and I dont want to use '*', how can i achieve output?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `select first_name, last_name from table1` in your stored procedure?

Comment: I`m getting output when executing stored procedure directly in sql server, but on executing mule., it is not accepting the parameters I passed. Its only accepting select * .  I`m not sure the technical reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting more than one column you can use the sample below. Kindly replace with appropriate columns.

```
select actimgUsername,actimgpass,accountName from vendors with(nolock) where actimgUsername = #[flowVars.userName] and actimgpass = #[flowVars.passWord] and accountname = #[flowVars.accountName]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Getting Null output on using with(nolock).

Comment: Kindly place the query you have used.

Comment: `USE [mydb]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sample1]    Script Date: 8/19/2016 12:10:55 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sample1]
AS
BEGIN
declare @hidden  INT
SELECT geo_name,id_definition
FROM geo with(nolock)
WHERE flag_hidden = @hidden
END`

Comment: Kindly add your Mule flow.xml

Answer (score 0):

I have used cursors to get output in mule flow

`DECLARE @fName varchar(50), @lName varchar(50)

DECLARE abc CURSOR -- Declare cursor

LOCAL SCROLL STATIC

FOR

Select firstName, lastName FROM myTable

OPEN abc -- open the cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName

INTO @fName, @lName

PRINT @fName + ' ' + @lName -- print the name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

FETCH NEXT FROM cursorName

INTO @fName, @lName

PRINT @fName + ' ' + @lName -- print the name

END

CLOSE abc -- close the cursor

DEALLOCATE abc -- Deallocate the cursor`